# Переключатель в HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Помогите, пожалуйста. Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Для мужчин" поменять изображение, а также в будущем изменять другие элементы? На данный момент пытаюсь сделать так:

```
<input type="radio" name="button" id="button1" checked="checked" value="woman">
<label for="button1">ДЛЯ ЖЕНЩИН</label>
<input type="radio" name="button" id="button2" value="man">
<label for="button2">ДЛЯ МУЖЧИН</label>
```

но ничего не получается :( получается только менять цвет кнопок.
Заранее спасибо[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например:

```css
img {
  display: none;
  max-width: 100%;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

#man:checked~#label-man {
  border-color: red;
}

#woman:checked~#label-woman {
  border-color: red;
}

#man:checked~#img-man {
  display: block;
}

#woman:checked~#img-woman {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  <input type="radio" name="man" id="man" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="man" id="woman">
  
  <label for="man" id="label-man">Man</label>
  <label for="woman" id="label-woman">Woman</label>
  
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519058082700-08a0b56da9b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=eefa9be00575de989c32ab5dbe1315a9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="" id="img-man">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=a3fa46375259c39d07d0227e8ade6daa&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="" id="img-woman">
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Поясните пожста, как этот синтаксис назвается `#woman:checked~#label-woman`? Хочу погуглить-почитать, не видал подобных селекторов.

Comment: соседние селекторы

Comment: @tym32167, читайте о селекторах https://webref.ru/layout/advanced-html-css/complex-selectors

Comment: ага, большое спасибо!